# тип real PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, float

Необходимо хранить числа, которые должны иметь точность 4 знака после запятой и имеют разрядность 7. Для работы с этими числами в c++ я использовал тип float, который вполне успешно хранит 7 десятичных разрядов. Однако, когда я загрузил эти данные в postgresql, то обнаружил, что числа округлились, после чего выяснил, что в postgresql real имеет разрядность 6. Получается, нужно хранить эти числа в double precision, но, очень бы не хотелось хранить 4 лишних байта, потому что я планирую запрашивать большие объемы данных и поэтому боюсь, что скорость получения клиентом данных значительно упадет, потому что, очевидно, данные запроса с типом double precision будут весить в два раза больше. Выиграю ли я что-нибудь в если задам тип decimal или numeric? Или, может быть, есть другие варианты решения этой проблемы?

Comment: IMHO, немного странный подход: использовать psql и пытаться экономить на спичках.

Comment: @PinkTux, не очень понял, что вы имеете в виду?)

Comment: население планеты растет и скоро борьба за все ресурсы обострится :-) с double будет быстрее работать, я думаю, поскольку  фиксированная длина и кодирование чисел оптимальное

Comment: Просто используйте тот тип данных, который подходит для вашей задачи и не думайте об экономии пары байт на запись. Не тот случай, где это должно как-то волновать. Вы ж не думаете, что размер базы будет равен побайтной сумме размеров всех полей в таблицах? Для примера: только что созданная пустая база в постгрес 9.5 уже занимает у меня около 8 Mb.

Comment: @PinkTux, меня в данном случае больше тревожит скорость выполнения запроса, я планирую запрашивать большие объемы данных из БД, и боюсь, что в таком случае select-ы будут выполняться медленнее.

Comment: Во-первых, вопрос был именно о "выигрыше по памяти". Во-вторых,   скорость выполнения запросов зависит от кучи разных факторов. Забейте таблицы тестовыми данными и отпрофилируйте ваши запросы с разными типами нужных полей (см. EXPLAIN ANALYZE) - понятней станет.

Comment: на скорость выполнения запросов sql существенно повлияет наличие индекса по полю, если выборка осуществляется по диапазону значений этого поля, а разница в несколько байт сколько бы то ни было существенной разницы не повлечет.

Comment: @Eugene Bartosh, я опять слегка некорректно выразился, я знаю про индексы, я говорю о том, что, допустим, если я запрошу у сервера 100 тысяч строк с данными типа real, они, очевидно, придут клиенту быстрее, чем 100 тысяч строк с данными типа double precision, потому что весить эти данные будут в два раза меньше

Comment: @bronstein87, разумеется так, ну а какие тут варианты - если надо столько значит надо... что будет быстрее работать numeric(8,2) или double - проще всего узнать сделав несложный тест - сделать 2 таблицы (первичные ключи + числовое поле), в одной числовое поле double в другой numeric(8,2), заполнить 100 тыс случайными числами, выполнить выборку на каждой и сравнить время выполнения - за час управитесь. для полноты можно проиндексировать по числовому полю,сравнить еще время заполнения каждой, а потом запросить данные с сортировкой

Comment: @bronstein87, и может быть неправильно гонять 100 тыс записей прямо вот в первозданном виде - на той стороне что-то с ними будет делать программа, как-то агрегировать наверно, вот задача как можно больше обработки и агрегации сделать на стороне субд, а передавать уже результат - 100 тыс записей никогда не нужны на клиенте за один раз.

Comment: тип float(7) не работает? Если почитать страницу документации о числовых типах данных Postgressql дальше таблицы типов, то можно найти упоминание поддержки float(p). Может это то, что Вам нужно.

Comment: @EugeneBartosh, мне бывают нужны на клиенте выборки до ста миллионов записей :)

Comment: от decimal и numeric точно проиграете в объеме. они хранятся в двоично кодированном десятичном формате. 1 байт на 2 цифры плюс от 3 до 8 байт накладных расходов (почему столько накладных не знаю, но так в доке сказано, для чистого BCD их быть не должно.)

Comment: Наверняка передача данных происходит быстрее, чем их обработка. Поэтому экономить на размере данных "в проводах" никакого смысла нет.

Comment: @Sergey, нет, float(24), тоже 6 цифр...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Или, может быть, есть другие варианты решения этой проблемы?

Я бы поступил исходя из следующего:

- Использование `double precision` обеспечивает хранение "более точных" данных. Когда-нибудь потом как найдется
- Отдавать число с плавающей в виде двух чисел: целая часть(`integer` - 4 байта) и дробная (`smallint` - 2 байта), итого нужные 6 байт:

`select pg_column_size(1111111::integer)+pg_column_size(2222::smallint) AS "Size"`

```
    Size
    -----------
    6
```

**На уровне предположения ...**

Уменьшение скорости обработки запросов с кастами - будет ничтожно мало по отношению к факторам, влияющим на передачи больших объемов результатов.

Comment: судя по тому, что написал человек в самом нижнем ответе здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402019/postgresql-optimizing-columns-size-for-numeric-fields , 7 разрядный numeric занимает 10 байт, так что каст в decimal или numeric не поможет

Comment: вы правы, вопрос отредактировал - новый вариант решения